# Print TextField on button click - printing incorrectly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm attempting to incorporate a function in my react app, where a user will input a search term, and when the button is pressed it will go search it. (text input and buttons are using material-ui components) For now I just want it to print the term to the console log to check its okay. When running the below code, the output is: "[object Object]. Does anyone know why that is?

```
 import React from 'react';
 import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
 import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

class searchText extends React.Component {
  state = {
    searchTerm: null,
  }

  handleClick = (searchTerm) => {
    this.setState({ searchTerm });
  }

  render() {
    const { searchTerm } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className ="Search">
        <TextField 
          id = "outlined-search"
          label="Enter Query"
          type = "search"
          className ="Search"
          variant="filled"
          value = {searchTerm}
         />

        <Button
         onClick={() =>{console.log("search: " +{searchTerm}); }}
         varient ="contained"
         classname="goButton" >
         Enter Query Here!
        <Button/>
     </div>
    );
  }
}
```

export default Search

*update: fixed typos*

Comment: How are you calling `handleClick` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your have not any function to get the input value and set that value in state.
Try this.

```
// function for TextField Value Change
    getvalue=(event)=>{
        this.setState({
          searchTerm:event.target.value
        })
    }
// function for button click
    handleClick = () => {
        console.log(this.state.searchTerm)
    }

                <TextField 
                  id = "outlined-search"
                  label="Enter Query"
                  type = "search"
                  className ="Search"
                  variant="filled"
                  value = {this.state.searchTerm}
                  onChange={this.getvalue}
                 />
```

Comment: Hi, I put in these changes, and when I put "onClick={handleClick} into the button it gives me an error saying handleClick is not defined

Comment: Use this.handleClick into the button.
like onClick={this.handleClick}

Answer (score 0):

The `+ searchTem` coerces the object into a string, which in your case is `[object Object]`

Just change it to:

```
console.log("search: ", searchTerm)
```

You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#Outputting_text_to_the_console

Comment: Hi, I tried this and now the output is just printing as 'null' no matter what my search term is

Answer (score 0):

Right now your'e not calling handleClick as you just console log it. That means that you're not changing/setting the state.searchTerm to anything. It's the handleClick that will update the state. So the value will always be null. Also you have a typo in your handleClick:

Your parameter says "serchTerm" ... it should say "searchTerm". You missed an a there ;)

Comment: Hi, so I changed the code so that onClick calls handleClick with ={handleClick} and the console.log is now within the handle click. But running this throws an error saying that handleClick is not defined? ((I also fixed the typo thank you))

Comment: Since this is a class component you have to call this.handleClick

Answer (score 0):

Classes use PascalCase as they are components, not simple functions. The Buttons component were badly terminated and maybe you can just simply call your function handler when the user clicks on the button and then show the state on the console

```
class SearchText extends React.Component {
  state = {
    searchTerm: null,
  }

  handleClick = (term) => {

    this.setState({ searchTerm: term });
    console.log(this.state.searchTerm)
  }

  render() {
    const { searchTerm } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className ="Search">
        <TextField 
          id = "outlined-search"
          label="Enter Query"
          type = "search"
          className ="Search"
          variant="filled"
          value = {searchTerm}
         />

        <Button
         onClick={this.handleClick}
         varient ="contained"
         classname="goButton" >
         Enter Query Here!
        </Button>
     </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Hope helps :)

Comment: Hi, I tried this and the first line throws an error if I use this.state instead of state (unexpected token, constructor, method, accessor, property expected) if I run it without the this.state, it comes back saying handleClick is not defined